# Symbols for meet and join (bigger \wedge and \vee)

Tags: math-operators, mathjax

I'd like to know how to get the `\wedge` and `\vee` shaped things in the image below to be that size. I found `\bigwedge` and `\bigvee`, but they're *too* big.

[image]

You can see the source pdf for youself [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s097-applied-category-theory-january-iap-2019/lecture-videos-and-readings/18-s097iap19textbook.pdf) if you like: Definition 1.81.

Edit: So far the closest I've found is to just use the unicode characters ⋁ and ⋀.

Edit 2: I apologize to the people who already answered. I should have clarified that I'm looking for something that can work in MathJax, and perhaps that doesn't exist, as it seems I need to use special packages to get the size I want. **I'll still accept the best answer that fits the title just in case someone comes along without this limitaiton.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is best to use \bigwedge and \bigvee. This way, subscript and superscript will adapt depending on whether you are in text mode or math mode. E.g.,

```
Consider \( \bigwedge_{a\in A} p_a \) and
\[
\bigvee_{i=1}^n p_i.
\]
```

Comment: Oh, I failed to see what you were saying on my first pass. `\bigX` in inline (`\(\bigX\)`) mode looks to be about the same size as what's used on the document. But I'm rendering in MathJax so it could very well be exactly what they used.

Answer (score 4):

With `scalerel`, you can specify the vertical footprint you want the symbol to occupy.  Here, it occupies the footprint of `j`, and automatically handles changes in math style, as shown in the 3rd line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\mywedge{\scalerel*{\bigwedge}{j}}
\begin{document}
$p=\wedge_{a\in A}$

$p=\bigwedge_{a\in A}$

$p=\mywedge_{a\in A\mywedge A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

p.s. You can introduce `\mathbin` (or other) to the `\mywedge` definition if you want the symbol to exhibit certain associated properties.